# How to resolve the undefined error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')" error when using a scrollable primeng-table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

I am using a p-table with it's 'scrollable' set as 'true' and 'scrollHeight' set as '288px'. The problem arises when the table has less data and the height remains less than 288px. The error shown at the time is as follows.

```
core.js:6486 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at Table.scrollTo (primeng-table.js:1189)
    at Table.resetScrollTop (primeng-table.js:1153)
    at Table._filter (primeng-table.js:1028)
    at Table.ngOnChanges (primeng-table.js:262)
    at Table.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1498)
    at callHook (core.js:2536)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8454)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:8437)
```

This arises because the 'viewWrapperChild' property remains undefined when the table height is less than the scrollHeight. But my table is dynamic as the data that I want can sometimes increase or decrease affecting the table height which requires me to use the scroll feature.

How can I avoid getting this error?

The code is as follows.

```
<p-table
    [value]="records"
    [scrollable]="true"
    scrollHeight="288px"
> 
   <ng-template let-col pTemplate="header">
              //Headings
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template
        let-col
        let-rowData
        let-i="rowIndex"
        pTemplate="body"
    > 
       //Table body
    </ng-template>

</p-table>
```

Edit:
Angular version: 12.2.12,
Primeng version: 12.2.2.

Comment: Can you try setting min-height on your <p-table> ?

Comment: What version of Angular & PrimeNg are you using?

Comment: A demo code to replicate this issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here's what I discovered after some experimenting:
PrimeNg Table has a TableState: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12-lts/#/table. I noticed that when the state is stored in localstorage and the page with the table was revisited, the error was thrown. I removed the entry from localstorage and the problem was gone...